# Is there a way to access an Apex WebService method via C# without logging into SalesForce in code?

Tags: c#, salesforce, apex-code

I've created an APEX Method in SalesForce that I would like a third party to access. I do not want this third party to have a SalesForce login, but I'd like them to access the method. The only way I've seen this done is by consuming a WSDL and then using a binding login. How can I just expose this service to the world without login requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, here is [an answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-have-a-public-apex-rest-api/) to a similar question on the Salesforce Stack Exchange site.

The question here is asking about exposing restful web services, but the same principal of using a Salesforce Site can be applied to your situation.

Here is a [developerforce forum post](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Exposing-Apex-Web-Service-class-via-Force-com-Sites/td-p/209290) with someone trying to use Apex Web Services